# What's the difference between the c9.io, cloud9-ide, and cloud9 tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

When posting something about Cloud9, I often find myself using all three tags ([c9.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c9.io), [cloud9-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud9-ide), and [cloud9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud9)), because they all seem to describe the same thing.

What's the difference between them? When should I use one over the other?

EDIT:
As Cody Gray mentioned, I do believe these are all the same topic and should be merged. I was wondering if anyone else had noticed this or felt the same way.

Cloud9 is solely an IDE. And c9.io is just the website for Cloud9.

So I suggest that all of these tags are merged into a tag called `Cloud9` (or cloud9 if it must be lowercased or a new tag can't be made), since that's the name of the site as a whole.

Comment: Seems to me like they should be made synonyms...

Comment: Okay, so you have a limited number of tags to use (5) and you decide to use 3 of them that are basically the same to categorize your question? That doesn't seem smart on your part.  Try to use one tag for each important aspect of your question instead of 5 equivalent or nearly equivalent ones...

Comment: As someone who uses Cloud9 and asks a lot of questions about it, you would be the person in the best position to answer this question. How might these tags be different? Does it make sense to have a different tag for the IDE versus for the product, or is the product just the IDE? If you don't think we need three tags, then [edit] the question to propose merging and/or synonymizing them. (Tags are not something created by moderators and handed down to users with a fixed purpose. Rather, they're created and defined by the community. Please help us refine the tags if they're not working well!)

Comment: @CodyGray edited. I'm fairly new to Stack so I'm still figuring out how things work. Thanks for explaining how I should do that.

Comment: I think there should be a single tag, `cloud9-ide`. That's the product, and the only thing programmers can ask about on SO that's on topic. Questions about their website, or the company itself, are not on topic.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That makes sense. I like the topic argument, since questions about the C9 community and such won't be received well here.